# Android Game Center, SHA1 key

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

When I linked my android app to the game center it asked for the SHA1 key. I gave it the android debug key. My release key obviously has a different SHA1. The problem is that I already published the game. The app is only published on Alpha release. Anyway do I have to relink the app to game center with the release version of the SHa1, or is the developer console smart enough to sort it out?

Comment: You'll have to relink it in the Game Center. Now that your application is published, you won't be able to change the sha-1 there (unless you're willing to re-publish it as a new application).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get SHA1 from your apk file by using terminal.Try to search for "obtaining SHA1 from apk file".When you obtain it,enter it to the developer console.

Comment: No this is the exact answer you are looking for. You said that you released your game but there is the debug key of your game in the console,not release key.So,the solution is get the release key and put it in the console instead of the debug key.Are you available to understand that? If your problem isn't that,then explain it more precisely and help people who are trying to help you! Istead of downvoting! I suggest you to search how to get the release key from apk file.Do that in your spare time when not downvoting the true answers!

Comment: What happened NJGUY? why did you delete your old comment? You noticed that I am right coz.Then why my reply is sytill downvoted? :) I will never help somebody again because people like you just getting the answer and downvoting instead of appreciating the help :)

Comment: I gave you the answer